# How can I print the for loop values in the button widget to the application screen?-Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, for-loop, widget

I'm learning Flutter. I have a problem. When I press the button, I want the values in the for loop to be printed on the application screen.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("For Döngüsü"),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text("Sayilar"),
              onPressed: () {
                for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
                  Text("$i");
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [list](https://api.dart.dev/be/180791/dart-core/List-class.html) on state class and widget on it.Then I am using [ListView.builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) to show the widget on app screen.

```dart
List<Widget> items = [];
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("For Döngüsü"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            child: Text("Sayilar"),
            onPressed: () {
              for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
                items.add(Text("$i"));
              }
              setState(() {}); //update the ui
            },
          ),
          Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: items.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => items[index]))
        ],
      ));
}
```